# Mongo DB for Transaction DB and Date operations

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

We have a requirement of storing multiple collections of transactional data (only inserts and no updates). With my limited knowledge of NoSQL DB, I feel Mongo DB is the simple and good choice for DB. Is my approach correct?

Also while querying I will have to filter records between dates. I couldn't find proper example of storing and filtering "date" type in Mongo collections. Can someone please help me with proper way of storing "date" type and writing filter queries?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB can easily handle your requirements for storing transactional data.   The preferred format for your date is to have it stored in your collection in the [BSON Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types) format  which is easier to use with queries and sorting.  The use of "new Date" below uses the [ISODate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#date) wrapper to format the date correctly.

example:

```
use foo_test
db.foo.drop()
db.foo.insert(
      {Quote:"Many of life's failures are people who did not realize how close they were to success when they gave up.", 
      Author: "Thomas Edison",
      Date: new Date("1931-01-31")});

db.foo.insert(
      {Quote:"In this world nothing can be said to be certain, except death and taxes.", 
      Author: "Benjamin Frankin",
      Date: new Date("1789-11-13")});

db.foo.insert(
      {Quote:"Houston, we've had a problem here", 
      Author: "Jim Lovell - Apollo 13 Commander",
      Date: new Date("1970-04-15")});

db.foo.insert(
      {Quote:"There aren't many downsides to being rich, other than paying taxes and having relatives asking for money.", 
      Author: "Bill Murray",
      Date: new Date("2005-03-14")});
```

Sample query to find a document with a specific Date which will return just 1 document of the sample data:

```
db.foo.find({Date: ISODate("1931-01-31")}).pretty();

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e0a749e4901a8bc1ab69f6"),
    "Quote" : "Many of life's failures are people who did not realize how close they were to success when they gave up.",
    "Author" : "Thomas Edison",
    "Date" : ISODate("1931-01-31T00:00:00Z")
}
```

Sample query to find all documents between two dates which will return 2 documents of the sample data:

```
db.foo.find({Date:{$gte:ISODate("1931-01-31"),$lte:ISODate("1970-05-01")}}).pretty();

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e0a749e4901a8bc1ab69f6"),
    "Quote" : "Many of life's failures are people who did not realize how close they were to success when they gave up.",
    "Author" : "Thomas Edison",
    "Date" : ISODate("1931-01-31T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e0a749e4901a8bc1ab69f8"),
    "Quote" : "Houston, we've had a problem here",
    "Author" : "Jim Lovell - Apollo 13 Commander",
    "Date" : ISODate("1970-04-15T00:00:00Z")
}
```